# how to create redirects via database in Shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

in Shopware 5 you can create redirects via the database by adding an entry to the table "s_core_rewrite_urls". You just need "org_path" and "path". Is there a similar way to create redirects in Shopware 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The corresponding table in Shopware 6 would be `seo_url`.

For example, if you want to create an additional seo url for a product, you could do it programmatically like that:

```php
$productId = 'b16f0df6a15b44e2b723a2f262b8b1cd';
$repository = $this->container->get('seo_url.repository');
$canonicalSeoUrl = $repository->search(
    (new Criteria())->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('foreignKey', $productId)),
    Context::createDefaultContext()
)->first();
$behavior = new CloneBehavior(['seoPathInfo' => 'my/new/seo/url', 'isCanonical' => false]);
$repository->clone($canonicalSeoUrl->getId(), Context::createDefaultContext(), null, $behavior);
```

By setting `isCanonical` to `false` in the clone behavior, a request of the new URL will redirect to the canonical URL.

If it has to be SQL, the equivalent query could look like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO `seo_url` (`id`, `language_id`, `sales_channel_id`, `foreign_key`, `route_name`, `path_info`, `seo_path_info`, `is_canonical`, `is_modified`, `is_deleted`, `custom_fields`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)
SELECT UNHEX(UPPER(MD5(RAND()))) as id, 
  `language_id`, `sales_channel_id`, `foreign_key`, `route_name`, `path_info`, 
  'another/seo/url' as seo_path_info, 0 as is_canonical,
  `is_modified`, `is_deleted`, `custom_fields`, `created_at`, `updated_at`
FROM `seo_url`
WHERE `foreign_key` = UNHEX(UPPER('b16f0df6a15b44e2b723a2f262b8b1cd')) 
AND `is_canonical` = 1;
```